# findViewById vs setId

Tags: android, view

all throughout the developer [documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) & [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial), they reccomend use of `findViewById()` to "Find a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle)" so i exclusively had been using that everywhere i needed a view to reference something in an xml file. this had caused a number of problems, like if i needed to use a view within a static method, or, as far as i can tell, any method aside from `onCreate`. recently i stumbled upon `setId()` which, in addition to being briefer to write and being more readable since it is following the standard "getters & setters" protocol, also seems to have no requirements as to where you use it within your app.

what actually is the difference between:

[setId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) - "Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number."

&

[findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) - "Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view."

are they interchangeable? are there circumstances that only allow use of one or the other?

Comment: it seems that calling `setId` on a view before calling `findViewById` on it causes a fc where there didn't used to be one, but maybe there are other things going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are completely different methods. In fact, `setId` is useful to set an ID of a view so that you can use `findViewById` later to find it again. You use `findViewById` when you know the ID of a view, and you want to get the actual `View` object associated with that ID. You use `setId` when you already have a `View` object, and you want to set an identifier for it, so that later on you can find that same `View` object again using `findViewById`.

Comment: so if i was reusing a view, i could do `EditText view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thinga);`first and then later just do `view.setId(R.id.thingb);` etc?

Comment: If you're just reusing the view, the `findViewById` call you specified will work just fine. The ID remains whatever it was before though, so there's no need to set it again.

Comment: i meant if i wanted a view to be associated with `(R.id.this_thing)` and then do things with it, like change the visibility or something, then later i want that view to be associated with `(R.id.that_thing)` so that i can recycle the view, so that there are fewer objects

Comment: It's hard to say without a more concrete example, but it's probably usually a bad idea to be changing the ID around like that. That said, what you're suggesting *could* work. I wouldn't do it unless absolutely necessary though. Better to just let GC take care of cleaning up that `View` and use a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Using findViewById you trying to find view that already "named" and you need to perform some operations after you inflated layout.

Using setId you set up a name for a view (e.g. that was created programmatically) to be able find this view in future by findViewById.

You could use findViewById  not only onCreate. Each ViewGroul allow you to find their children by ids.

Comment: i think i meant to say that i couldn't use `findViewById` in static methods, only `setId` would work